# How many ways can a store order $50$ cases of soda if it does not order more than $20$ cases of Coke?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> An employee of a grocery store is placing an order for soda. There are 8 varieties of soda and they are sold in cases. Each case contains is all the same variety. The store will order 50 cases total. How many ways are there to place the order if she does not order more than 20 cases of Coke?

I have been working on this problem for a while but am confused by how to go about solving it. The order in which the cases are selected is irrelevant which leads me to believe it's a combination yet there is a limit on how many cases can be selected for Coke. I'm not sure how to include this limit in the calculation. Would the calculation for the combination be divide by 20 to include the limit?

Comment: This is horrendous. There are over 30,000 partitions of 50 into 8 different parts. For example, 50=23+11+7+6+1+1+1+0. Take that one, there are 7 choices for which gets 23 cases, 7 choices for which gets 11, 6 choices for which gets 7, 5 choices for which gets 6, 4 choices for which gets 0. Your best bet is to write a short program to do it.

Comment: This is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) with restrictions.  Do you know how to solve the problem without the restriction that there are at most $20$ cases of Coke?  Please include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Were there no restrictions on Coke, it'd be a simple stars and bars problem, $\dbinom{50+8-1}{8-1}$ ways

To count and exclude invalid orders, pre-place orders of **21** cases of Coke, and then order the balance $29$ cases (including Coke) unrestrictedly, thus

$\dbinom{50+8-1}{8-1} - \dbinom{29+8-1}{8-1}$